# Bootstrapping: Is there a faster way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics

I'm trying to compute the bootstrap statistic of the total of an array and I'm wondering if this can be improved in terms of speed, please?

```
from numpy import sum
from numpy.random import choice

def bootstrap(observed_array: array, number_of_bootstraps: int = 10000) -> array:
    number_of_elements = len(observed_array)
    bootstrap_estimates = []
    for _ in range(number_of_bootstraps):
        indices = choice(number_of_elements, size=number_of_elements, replace=True)
        bootstrap_sample = observed_array[indices]
        bootstrap_estimate = bootstrap_sample.sum()
        bootstrap_estimates.append(bootstrap_estimate)
    return array(bootstrap_estimates)
```

Thanks for any suggestions here.

Comment: The one trick I know is to avoid constructing the bootstrap sample as a new array and instead just create a list of weights which are k/n for any items which are chosen (usually k = 1 but k > 1 if it was chosen more than once) and 0 otherwise. Then compute the weighted sum of the original sample of n items. I guess another idea to avoid array construction is to just do a nested index i.e. sum over observed_array[indices[i]] for i from 0 to number of items in bootstrap sample. Hope this helps.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for your suggestions. Are you saying `bootstrap_estimates.append(sum(observed_array[bootstrap_indices]))` is faster as I wouldn't be creating additional arrays?

Comment: No, `observed_array[bootstrap_indices]` creates a new array whether it is assigned to a variable or not.